# How to create a View showing subscribed content?

Tags: 7, views, notifications

I want to create a view which will display all the posts user has subscribed to (very much like the Facebook homepage).

I have used the [Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions) module for allowing the user to subscribe to posts, but I am unable to configure the Views.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Subscriptions does not currently have views support.

There is an issue for it here - http://drupal.org/node/269472 - with a patch, however it is missing some parts and the author has not yet responded with the missing code.

I need it so I will be finishing the patch sometime in the next week unless someone beats me to it.

Until then, unless you want to code the views support yourself there is no views/subscriptions solution.